# Why is Maybe's Semigroup instance biased towards Just and the Monoid uses Nothing as its empty element?

Tags: haskell, option-type, monoids, semigroup

`Maybe` expresses computations that might not produce a result due to an error. Therefore such computations must be short circuited.

Now `Maybe`'s Semigroup/Monoid instances seem to break with this semantics, because the former is biased towards `Just` and the latter treats the error case `Nothing` as its empty element:

```
Just "foo" <> Nothing -- Just "foo"
Nothing <> Just "bar" -- Just "bar"
Just "foo" <> Just "bar" -- Just "foobar"
Nothing <> Nothing -- Nothing
```

I would expect `Nothing` for the first two cases.

Here is the alternative implementation (hopefully it is correct/lawful):

```
instance Semigroup a => Semigroup (Maybe a) where
    Nothing <> _       = Nothing
    _       <> Nothing = Nothing
    Just a  <> Just b  = Just (a <> b)

instance Monoid a => Monoid (Maybe a) where
  mempty = Just mempty
```

I don't want to say that these alternative instances are better. But they seem useful too. So why was a selection made in the first place instead of leaving the implementation to the user?

Comment: Well that is one of the constraints a monoid has to satisfy: there is an empty element `0`, and `0 + x = x + 0 = x`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, yes, and OP's does satisfy that. Note: mempty = *Just* mempty.

Comment: @luqui: but then that would mean that we have a `mempty` for `a` right?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, we do, because of the `Monoid a =>` constraint.

Comment: Aargh... Yes, I overlooked the `Monoid a` constraint :(

Comment: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/1189#comment:1 link to the mailing list discussion, with its summary

Comment: You make the assumption that there is an "error" or "failure" semantic in the maybe, versus just a Nothing , Something semantic. The Nothing<>Something semantic is, is somehow equivalent to a list with 0 or 1 element.
In that case, it seams natural that the concept of "empty" correspond to Nothing.
For a list, you wouldn't expect `mempty` to be `[mempty]` wouldn't you ?

Comment: @mb14 Sure, you can reduce the semantics of a type to its bare minimum. But `List` is a Monoid in its own right, whereas `Maybe` imposes a constraint on `a` (either `Semigroup a` or `Monoid a` depending on the implementation). So in case of `Maybe` we have to pick one.

Comment: Related: [Monoids for Maybe](https://byorgey.wordpress.com/2011/04/18/monoids-for-maybe/); [Option](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Semigroup.html#t:Option).

Answer (score 8):

Your instance is actually a special case of a much more general instance for applicative functors.

```
newtype LiftA f a = LiftA { getLiftA :: f a }

instance (Applicative f, Semigroup a) => Semigroup (LiftA f a) where
    LiftA x <> LiftA y = LiftA $ liftA2 (<>) x y

instance (Applicative f, Monoid a) => Monoid (LiftA f a) where
    mempty = LiftA $ pure mempty
```

Which I assumed would be in the standard library somewhere (under a different name probably) but I couldn't find it.  But the existence of this general instance could be one reason to choose the library version of `Maybe`, which is more of `Maybe`'s special power.  On the other hand, it's quite nice when your algebraic structures are all coherent with each other; i.e. when a type is an `Applicative`, use the "`LiftA`"-style instance whenever possible (on all [F-algebra](https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2013/03/12/constructions-on-typeclasses-part-1-f-algebras/) classes).

On the third hand (!), we can't have coherence everywhere, since the library instance agrees with `Maybe`'s `MonadPlus` instance.  This is strikingly parallel to the fact that there are two monoids on natural numbers: addition and multiplication.  For numbers, we just picked not to have *any* monoid instance because it's unclear which to use.

In conclusion, I don't know.  But maybe this information was helpful.

Comment: So decision/compromises have to be made in Haskell, just like in imperative languages. But the possibility to decide is limited to the cases that the underlying mathematical framework allows, which is a big win - probably.

Comment: I see this issue coming from the core idea of typeclasses which is a sort of pun, pretending that types and algebraic structures are in perfect correspondence (e.g. there is only one way a type can be a monad).  It's often, but not always true.  But making that little lie makes a *lot* of things very convenient and cuts down on a lot of mess that would otherwise be there, manually keeping track of which algebraic structure we're talking about.  But then there are cases like this where we have to pick favorites and/or disambiguate manually, and it can be cumbersome.

Comment: Your answer along with the comment provides a great explanation for a vague question. Thank you!

Comment: ["on the gripping hand"](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/O/on-the-gripping-hand.html), perhaps? :)

Answer (score 3):

I think the idea behind this is that `Maybe` is supposed to have the semantics that are actually only properly expressed by [`Option`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Semigroup.html#t:Option): it takes any semigroup and makes a monoid out of it, by adding `Nothing` as an ad-hoc “free mempty”. I.e. actually the instances should be

```
instance Semigroup a => Semigroup (Maybe a) where
  Nothing <> a = a
  a <> Nothing = a
  Just x <> Just y = Just $ x <> y

instance Semigroup a => Monoid (Maybe a) where
  mappend = (<>)
  mempty = Nothing
```

This is analogous to how `[]` gives the free monoid over *any* type, by adding both `mempty` and `<>`.

Of course, this requires that the `Semigroup` class is in `base`, which it wasn't until recently.

Corollary to this is that `mempty` becomes clearly pattern-matchable, because by parametricity it cannot depend on the contained type.

Practically speaking, this instance is arguably more useful then the one you propose, because as Luke remarked that is already covered by the `Applicative` instance so you can easily write `liftA2 (<>)` and `pure mempty`. Granted, the standard instance is also already covered by the `Alternative` instance, but `Alternative/MonadPlus` have always been considered as a bit hackish, inferior to the more mathematically impeccable `Semigroup`, `Monoid`, `Functor` and `Applicative`.